# Is there an idempotent hash function?

Tags: hash, idempotent

Is there a hash function that is idempotent? I know MD5 and SHA256 are not:

```
$ echo -n "hello world" | md5sum
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3  -
$ echo -n "5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3" | md5sum
c0b0ef2d0f76f0133b83a9b82c1c7326  -

$ echo -n "hello world" | sha256sum
b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9  -
$ echo -n "b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9" | sha256sum
049da052634feb56ce6ec0bc648c672011edff1cb272b53113bbc90a8f00249c  -
```

Is there a hash algorithm that can do something like this?

```
$ echo -n "hello world" | idempotentsum
abcdef1234567890
$ echo -n "abcdef1234567890" | idempotentsum
abcdef1234567890
```

If such an algorithm does exist, is it useful cryptographically? I.e. with reasonable inputs, is it computationally infeasible to guess the input with a known output?

If such an algorithm does not exist, does it not exist because nobody has bothered to find it or is it a mathematical impossibility?

**Context**

I'm working on a system where a user may want to save a password in a password manager. A particularly paranoid user may prefer to save the password in a hashed form rather than in plain text. I'd like the user to be able to authenticate with this hashed password. Rather than simply trying the authentication twice (once assuming the user's password is hashed and once assuming it is not), I wondered if there was an algorithm to let me only do it once.

I know there are alternative ways of allowing users to store authentication tokens rather than plain-text passwords. But this idea popped into my head, and I am curious. I couldn't find anything about this on Google or SO.

EDIT: I am not suggesting that allowing a user to authenticate with a hashed password means it is OK for the server to not salt/hash the password. The server must still salt/hash the original password or the client-side hashed password.

EDIT: I am not suggesting that allowing the user to log in with a client-side hashed password is a genuine security improvement. As far as I know the only possible benefit this would add is if the user used this password for more than one purpose. In that case, if the user's hashed password was discovered by an attacker, then only access to my service would be compromised rather than all services sharing that password. However, best practice is to not use the same password for multiple services.

Comment: i don't think that user who want to save password hashed is paranoid

Comment: @AndrewMedico: wikipedia says: *Idempotence (/ˌaɪdɨmˈpoʊtəns/ EYE-dəm-POH-təns) is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science, that can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application.* I think it's definitely the *right* word here.

Comment: Users saving passwords on their end in hashed form is pointless. If the server accepts a particular string for login, that is by definition a "plaintext password". It doesn't matter if it's a random word or the output of a hash. It's actually much worse for security because if someone ever got a copy of the login database (say, maybe, a lost backup disk) they could immediately login as any user - without going to the trouble of cracking the hashes.

Comment: @Krab I don't use the term "paranoid" to necessarily mean anything bad. I could use the phrase "security conscious" instead. But I think a security conscious user would know to use a unique password for every website. Doing so negates any benefit of hashing the password on the client side, as far as I know.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I am not suggesting that hashing the password client side removes the need for hashing the password again server side. The server definitely needs to salt/hash the password. I do agree than in this case the user effectively has two passwords. The only point in hashing the password client side is if the user shares this password with other services (which of course is a bad idea). I provided the context to better explain how I arrived at this question. I do not actually believe this is a good use case for the algorithm I'm looking for. I will edit to make this more clear.

Comment: I think this is my first downvoted question. Can anyone suggest an improvement? Should I have excluded the "context" section because it is not relevant? Should I have posted to a different site (maybe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It's likely downvoted for being an authentication scheme with obvious and glaring vulnerabilities that should not be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Such a function is actually quite easy to find, and it doesn't weaken the cryptography of the system (except in an obvious and trivial way). We can actually transform any hashing function into an idempotent hashing function so long as we have a way of identifying if a given value is a potential output of the hashing function (in more formal language, if an element of the domain is also an element of the range).

(A potential method of doing this is just checking the size of the input element, as most hash functions attempt to uniformly output values up to a given size. This ignores the possibility of incorrectly identifying a value that can never be output from the hash function, but that would be specific to individual hashing functions.)

We then create a new method that checks whether a value can be output from the hashing function, and if so, returns the value back. Otherwise, the function proceeds as normal and hashes the value. This new function is as secure as the original function except for hashing values of its range, for which its completely insecure, but that's unavoidable in an idempotent hashing function.

Answer (score 0):

> If such an algorithm does exist, is it useful cryptographically?

Well, consider this: a hash typically is a map between two sets:

```
A -> B
```

where B is the set of possible hashes, and A is the set of things that are hashable.

Now, usually A is much bigger than B -- hashes are like shorter "checksums" that can be calculated from much larger streams of data.
Typically, you'd still want as little collisions as possible in your hash, meaning that statistically, all elements from B should have the same number of elements from A that map to them, and the elements from A that map to the same element in B should be "far away" from each other under some metric. This implies, that B tries as hard as possible to be the **whole** set of words of a constant length. It will be immensely harder to find a systematic function that does that, but still maps each element from B to the same element in B; you "enforce" collision. In general, that's a cryptographic weakness, and a serious one at that.

Now, considering your password case: I don't see how that would make any sense. It's cryptographically a bad idea to let your user authenticate with either his/her hashed password or in plain, because no matter what you'd do, you'd give away full information on how to forge authentication to all eavesdroppers.

Comment: I agree that key based authentication (such as SSH) is better than using passwords. But pretty much every website these days allows users to authenticate with their plain-text password--including most online banking. I'm as dissatisfied as the next person about the lack of adoption of client-side SSL certs. But I suspect the reason is that copying client keys to every device is simply too much to expect from the average web user.